# getting an Error Execution failed for task ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

i'm getting an Error Execution failed for task while generating release apk':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
it's working fine on debug mode.  i'm using "@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation": "^0.6.3", and i'm using below command to generate an apk

`./gradlew app:assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

```
> Task :@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/BackgroundLocation.java:10: error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist
import android.support.v4.util.TimeUtils;
                              ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/BackgroundGeolocationFacade.java:17: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/BackgroundGeolocationFacade.java:18: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/LocationTransform.java:4: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/LocationTransform.java:5: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/NotificationHelper.java:12: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/NotificationHelper.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class NotificationCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/SyncAdapter.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class NotificationCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/SyncAdapter.java:15: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/service/LocationServiceImpl.java:32: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/service/LocationServiceImpl.java:33: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/service/LocationServiceIntentBuilder.java:24: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
                                 ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/service/LocationServiceIntentBuilder.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@IntDef({
 ^
  symbol: class IntDef
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/LocationTransform.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    BackgroundLocation transformLocationBeforeCommit(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull BackgroundLocation location);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: interface LocationTransform
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/LocationTransform.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    BackgroundLocation transformLocationBeforeCommit(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull BackgroundLocation location);
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: interface LocationTransform
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/LocationTransform.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    @Nullable
     ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: interface LocationTransform
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/NotificationHelper.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
     ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: class NotificationHelper
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/NotificationHelper.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
     ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: class NotificationHelper
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/NotificationHelper.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
     ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: class NotificationHelper
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/service/LocationServiceImpl.java:739: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void setLocationTransform(@Nullable LocationTransform transform) {
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class LocationServiceImpl
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/service/LocationServiceImpl.java:743: error: cannot find symbol
    public static @Nullable LocationTransform getLocationTransform() {
                   ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class LocationServiceImpl
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/BackgroundLocation.java:824: error: cannot find symbol
            TimeUtils.formatDuration(elapsedRealtimeNanos / 1000000L, s);
            ^
  symbol:   variable TimeUtils
  location: class BackgroundLocation
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/BackgroundGeolocationFacade.java:199: error: cannot find symbol
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(serviceBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationServiceImpl.ACTION_BROADCAST));
        ^
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class BackgroundGeolocationFacade
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/BackgroundGeolocationFacade.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(serviceBroadcastReceiver);
            ^
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class BackgroundGeolocationFacade
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/BackgroundGeolocationFacade.java:489: error: cannot find symbol
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ^
  symbol:   variable ContextCompat
  location: class BackgroundGeolocationFacade
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/NotificationHelper.java:55: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NotificationHelper.SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID);
                              ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/NotificationHelper.java:55: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NotificationHelper.SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID);
                                                                       ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/SyncAdapter.java:144: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;
                          ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/SyncAdapter.java:147: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), NotificationHelper.SYNC_CHANNEL_ID);
                                            ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/SyncAdapter.java:218: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), NotificationHelper.SYNC_CHANNEL_ID);
                              ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/SyncAdapter.java:218: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), NotificationHelper.SYNC_CHANNEL_ID);
                                                                       ^
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/sync/SyncAdapter.java:231: error: cannot find symbol
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext().getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        ^
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class SyncAdapter
/Users/macsol/Desktop/project /kliq/node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/android/common/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/service/LocationServiceImpl.java:628: error: cannot find symbol
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        ^
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class LocationServiceImpl
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
33 errors

> Task :@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost
Download https://github.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/releases/download/v1.63.0-0/boost_1_63_0.tar.gz

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
485 actionable tasks: 33 executed, 452 up-to-date
macsol@192 android %
```